# MonoTouch - Reading in a file from the Main Bundle

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mainbundle

I have an application which I have written in MonoTouch.  I dropped a file called ARCSDev into the applications folder and included it in the project, I then tried to read in the file using the following code:

```
private void generateChart (int chartNumber, string palette)
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "ARCSDev");

            Loader loader = new Loader (filePath);
```

However my application can't seem to find the file, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a quick look you're trying to load from the "Documents" directory (i.e. the one you have read-write access, could access via iTunes and get backed up), while your own file is inside the application directory (which is read-only).

What you want is (likely) `NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath`

This Xamarin's [article](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/) covers this (and a lot more) about the iOS file system.